# Is it possible to connect to Sony Camera Remote API with hybrid mobile apps

Tags: phonegap-plugins, ionic2, sony, sony-camera-api

Since we need to have a UDP socket to discover the device, and since javascript seems not supporting UDP, is it possible to connect to Sony Camera Remote API with a javascript based mobile app (non native).

Comment: Is this a cordova app you are talking about? Have you tried a cordova based UDP plugin? Something like this : https://github.com/MobileChromeApps/cordova-plugin-chrome-apps-sockets-udp

Comment: @Robert : Yes it is. Ionic2 + Cordova. How did I miss that!  :)  I'll check. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As said in the comments, you can use Cordova to do the SSDP discovery.

However, as far as I can see, the API is HTTP-based.  So if you don't need discover (can write in the IP address and port manually), then this should be possible to do.

Did you ever get anywhere with this project?  I'd be interested in getting some LiveView and controlling a camera using Javascript.

Comment: Sorry. It was a sort of POC. I just moved to native.